# Import primeng TableModule gives error in Angular2

Tags: angular, primeng-table

I'm trying to run a very simple primeng table app. I installed primeng and primeicons. When I add this import in app.module.ts:

```
import { TableModule } from 'primeng/table';
```

It gives an error when compiling:

> Error: node_modules/primeng/table/table.d.ts:375:18 - error TS2707:
> Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration' requires between 7 and 8 type
> arguments.
>
> 375     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<TableBody,
> "[pTableBody]", never, { "columns": "pTableBody"; "template":
> "pTableBodyTemplate"; "value": "value"; "frozen": "frozen";
> "frozenRows": "frozenRows"; "scrollerOptions": "scrollerOptions"; },
> {}, never, never, false, never>;
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> Error: node_modules/primeng/table/table.d.ts:382:18 - error TS2707:
> Generic type 'ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration' requires between 6 and 8 type
> arguments.
>
> 382     static ɵdir: i0.ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration<RowGroupHeader,
> "[pRowGroupHeader]", never, {}, {}, never, never, false, never>;
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> Error: node_modules/primeng/table/table.d.ts:394:18 - error TS2707:
> Generic type 'ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration' requires between 6 and 8 type
> arguments.
>
> 394     static ɵdir: i0.ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration<FrozenColumn,
> "[pFrozenColumn]", never, { "frozen": "frozen"; "alignFrozen":
> "alignFrozen"; }, {}, never,  never, false, never>;
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> Error: node_modules/primeng/table/table.d.ts:412:18 - error TS2707:
> Generic type 'ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration' requires between 6 and 8 type
> arguments.
>
> 412     static ɵdir: i0.ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration<SortableColumn,
> "[pSortableColumn]", never, { "field": "pSortableColumn";
> "pSortableColumnDisabled": "pSortableColumnDisabled"; }, {}, never,
> never, false, never>;

What is it wrong here? Package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.0",
    "primeicons": "^6.0.1",
    "primeng": "^15.0.0-rc.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I think is that you are using the v15 primeng (rc too) with angular v14. Upgrade your Angular version or downgrade your primeng version so they match.

The official example works just fine without any errors: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tabledoc-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts you can check the versions for it from there.

Comment: I copy-pasted dependencies and dev-dependencies from this example, run 'npm i --force' and 'npm start' and got the following error: [error] Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\MyDocuments\General\JavaScript\angular\prime-ng-table-reorder\table-order-demo\node_modules\@angular\compiler\fesm2015\compiler.mjs not supported.